# Распарсить строку в массив регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

на входе имеем строку вида

> id:2 name:36Название kod:hjkhjk text:Описаghgfhние запроса kom:Комментарий администр script:Тело+Скрип23weта script:Тело:Скрипта script:Тело Скрипта param:Параметр пар ап апр патид

необходимо получить массив вида

```
id:2 
name:36Название 
kod:hjkhjk 
text:Описаghgfhние запроса 
kom:Комментарий администр 
script:Тело+Скрип23weта 
script:Тело:Скрипта 
script:Тело Скрипта 
param:Параметр пар ап апр пати
```

На данный момент получилось следующее выражение

```
(id|name|kod|text|kom|script|param):([\w]+)
```

использовал флаги /g/u

https://regex101.com/r/LBxq8B/1

как описать что первым символом в ключе может встречаться восклицательный знак "!"
для выражения `(id|name|kod|text|kom|script|param):(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)`

> id:2 !id:2 name:36Название !name:36Название kod:hjkhjk text:Описаghgfhние запроса kom:Комментарий администр script:Тело+Скрип23weта script:Тело:Скрипта script:Тело Скрипта param:Параметр пар ап апр патид

```
id:2 
!id:2 
name:36Название 
!name:36Название 
kod:hjkhjk 
text:Описаghgfhние запроса 
kom:Комментарий администр 
script:Тело+Скрип23weта 
script:Тело:Скрипта 
script:Тело Скрипта 
param:Параметр пар ап апр пати
```

Comment: [`(\w+):(.*?)(?=\s+(\w+:|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/8aD459/1)

Comment: а как добавить чтоб первый символ может быть ! а может его и не быть  в (id|name|kod|text|kom|script|param):(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду, но *может быть а может не быть* делается через вопросительный знак, в вашем случае `!?` - совпадет с пустой строкой или с восклицательным знаком, поставьте это где вам надо.

Comment: не получается  https://regex101.com/r/LBxq8B/6 регулярка считает продолжением предыдущей строки, добавил примеры в описание

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'id:2 name:36Название kod:hjkhjk text:Описаghgfhние запроса kom:Комментарий администр script:Тело+Скрип23weта script:Тело:Скрипта script:Тело Скрипта param:Параметр пар ап апр патид';

$patt = '~(?:id|name|kod|text|kom|script|param):[\w\h+]+(?=\s+)~u';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: не захватывает "script:Тело:Скрипта"

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @trollingchar , то что надо

только немного подправил регулярку чтоб брал только то что нужно

[(id|name|kod|text|kom|script|param):(.*?)(?=\s+\w+:|$)](https://regex101.com/r/LBxq8B/4/)